# Error: could not find function "list_spark_kernels"

Tags: data-science-experience

I'm following a [tutorial](http://datascience.ibm.com/blog/access-ibm-analytics-for-apache-spark-from-rstudio/) to access spark from RStudio on Data Science Experience.  However, a function listed in the tutorial is not available:

```
> list_spark_kernels()
Error: could not find function "list_spark_kernels"
```

I have the files `config.yml` and `.Rprofile` in my home folder:

```
> dir(all.files = TRUE)
 [1] "."                  ".."                 ".pki"               ".Rhistory"          ".Rprofile"         
 [6] ".rstudio"           "config.yml"         "ibm-sparkaas-demos" "lost+found"         "R"
```

I've also tried sourcing my .Rprofile but that did not work:

```
>  source(".Rprofile")
> list_spark_kernels()
Error: could not find function "list_spark_kernels"
```

I tried the `list_spark_kernels()` function earlier today and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case, anyone faces list_spark_kernels() not found.

Please `remove.packages("sparklyr")` from rstudio console and then restart rstudio.

Restart will reinstall sparklyr created for connecting to spark service.

Thanks,
Charles.